# Why this question is bad for this site?

Tags: support, closing

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41783/will-there-every-fix-the-mustve-been-my-imagination-feature

Is there any place I can ask it or I just need to google it myself?

or am I just being patronized? is it because I used the b word?

Comment: I would like to commend you for following the correct procedure and bringing this up on meta.  It shows that you really are trying to learn about the site and follow its rules, even if they don't always make sense to you.

Answer (score 19):

So, the problem with your question is more the fact that without being one of the developers of the game, this question can't be answered. As a result, any answers to the question wouldn't really be definitive or more correct than other answers; so, which answer would you accept, or vote up? It doesn't really lend itself towards getting decent answers based on fact, and the question becomes an opinion contest, something which we try to avoid here.

Or suppose that a blog post from one of the developers pops up or a patch is released. In the former situation(probably the best situation for your question) this question becomes easy to answer through a Google search for the time-being, meaning the answers aren't going to be particularly high quality or insightful, and then when a patch is released the question becomes obsolete; no one can find your question useful anymore since it doesn't matter, the problem was fixed. We try to stick with questions that will stand the test of time and remain useful even as time passes, to remain a comprehensive up-to-date source of gaming knowledge.

Comment: Similar arguments can be made against ITG!

Comment: @raven how I long for the violent death of identify-this-game; these Qs are the source of so many *terrible* tags as well.

Comment: I was asking if there was any blog post or anything that said something about this bug. its very hard to google and if someone is a big fan of the game they do know the answer. Can I re-ask it with like I did in this comment? will you save it then?

Comment: It is not hard to google. The fact that you haven't found anything in a google search (presuming you tried) means there's no timetable for changing it. Having played Skyrim and previous TES games, I am almost certain it will not be changed, based on Bethesda's previous treatment of stealth attacks.

Answer (score 10):

> **Please note, however, that site policies prohibit questions of the following types:**
>
> - Game and Mod Development (please ask development questions on Game Development Stack Exchange)
> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)
> - Shopping advice and recommendations
> - **Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases**
> - Piracy, and support with pirated games.

...sayeth thine FAQ. Read truly thine FAQ for Pete'th sake, m'lord!

Comment: To be fair, this doesn't explain *why* the question is bad for the site.

Comment: It's because it's speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases

Comment: @Juan Okay, haha. I guess no explanation needed then.

Comment: I did not ask about the future, but I wanted to know is there any information about fixing that bug. this information could have been obtained from a blog or a gaming website.

Answer (score 6):

All StackExchange sites, at their core, are about finding expert answers to problems that you're facing.  Specifically, read this section of the faq: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Your question isn't a "pratical problem" you're trying to get answer to.  It's more of a lightly veiled rant ("I don't agree with this implementation" essentially).  On top of that, it's unanswerable unless you have developer inside information.

Comment: I disagree, its a common bug and its answerable if you have developer inside information from a blog or a gaming website.

Comment: @iadapter It isn't a blocking bug. If you had an answer it wouldn't change anything. So it isn't a practical problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, the comments section on this question:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41744/why-game-developers-ignore-customers-feedback

answers the question you asked here.  What happened in there was a debate, a discussion about two differing opinions.  This is not a forum, it's not a place for debate.  It's a place for questions that can be answered, to be answered.  The intent of that question was to express an opinion, and get people to discuss that opinion.

I tried to answer your previous question, which was very similar:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41703/why-there-is-limit-on-amount-of-things-you-can-carry

by explaining inventory management.  I can give a factual answer about inventory management in Bethesda games and how it compares to other RPG games.  However, it's not possible to explain the motives or design goals of a game without being the designer of the game.  Even if I was the game designer responsible for inventory management at Bethesda, the best I could do is give you my opinion.  You'd still probably disagree with it, and that's fine, but discussing how your opinion on a subject differs from anyone else's opinion on a subject is not appropriate for this site.

A more appropriate place to ask your question is on Bethesda's forums, where Bethesda employees are possibly moderating the conversation and might provide insight into why they chose a particular system or why it works well (in their opinion) for their games.

The FAQ puts the general rule well, although it's a little ambiguous and may have tripped you up:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

You may have felt that you wanted someone to explain these concepts to you, but that's not the question that you posted.  Your question asks "I don't like X, and I wish it was different, are the designers crazy?"

Comment: debate was not mine choice, it was mod's or mod-like monsters that want to do debate. how could I have stopped them? thx for idea about Bethesda forum, I did not know they had one.

Comment: I was speaking of comments left by you, ratchet freak, and Killith, where you were debating the purpose of the weight limit.  There were no mods involved in that.

Comment: I see no debate, just trying to clarify some misconceptions. they were acting like mode attacking poor guy without any reason.